# Как включить описание функий C++ (WinAPI) в Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

В проектах .NET при наведение на метод или класс появляется описание:

[image]

Есть ли возможность добавить такое в проекты C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если кто-то написал функцию или класс, которые вы пытаетесь использовать в своём коде, и эти средства были предварительно сопровождены комментариями, то в всплывающей подсказке вы увидите то, что хотите. Во всяком случае, для голого С++ такого в студии нет. Не ленитесь и просматривайте документацию на специализированных сайтах. Всё равно в подсказке невозможно уместить всю необходимую информацию.

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно, у вас отключена эта возможность. Включить ее в Visual Studio 2012 можно так: 
Tools => Options => Text Editor => C/C++ => Advanced => в окне справа выбираете категорию IntelliSense, в ней первый пункт AutoQuickInfo устанавливаете в True

Comment: Моя ошибка. Я имел виду не описание функции, а именно действие которое она делает, примерно так: "Creates a thread to execute within the virtual address space of the calling process.". Возможно ли такое? В .Net,  я так понимаю, все документировано, а вот в случаии с С++?